# Bootbox.js - enable / disable button + custom jquery - How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, bootbox

I am using bootbox.js to display 2 controls in a modal:

- File Uploader
- Button to submit file.

This is what I have so far in my script section in my view:

```
     $('#uploadActivity').on('click', function() {
        var dialogHtml = '<form action="/Home/Load" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="frmSubmitActivity">';
        dialogHtml += '<input type="file" name="GarminActivity"/>';
        dialogHtml += '<div class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-primary has-spinner" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>';
        dialogHtml += '<span class="spinner"><i class="icon-spin icon-refresh"></i></span> @Resources.Upload</button></div>';

        bootbox.dialog({ message: dialogHtml, title: '@Resources.UploadActivity' });
    });
```

AS you can see, the user presses a button and the modal is displayed. And here are my questions:

1) If I present the button in the modal as disabled, how do I enable it when the users picks a file?

2) As you can see on my custom dialogHTML there is some spinner functionality, that is, when submiting a form a spinner icon is displayed in the button and disables all controls on form, this behaviour is on a javascript file that is referenced, but none of this happens. This is how (is working on other forms:

```
$("[type=submit]").on('click', function () {
var btn = $(this);
var form = $(this).closest('form');
if ($(form).valid()) {
    $(form).find('input, textarea, button, select').prop('readonly', 'readonly');
    $(btn).toggleClass('active');
    $(btn).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(form).submit();
}
```

});

I have been struggling for 5 days and I can't make it work. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

[Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Attach event handler to document instead of `[type=submit]` as it will be generated dynamically so it is not present at DOM ready so no event handler is attached to it.

And make sure sure you put this code in DOM ready .

```
$(document).on('click', '[type=submit]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop form submission
    var btn = $(this),
        form = $(this).closest('form');
    if (form.valid()) {
        form.find('input, textarea, button, select').prop('readonly', true);
        btn.toggleClass('active');
        btn.prop("disabled", true);
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

[event.preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

To enable button on file selection .

```
$(document).on('change', '[type=file][name=GarminActivity]', function () {
    var btn = $(this).closest('form').find('[type=submit]');
    btn.prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: I tried this... What is this suppose to do? I tried and nothing happened with the modal, however is still working with other forms.

Comment: I tried Tushar, but it's throwing an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when executing the valid() line, despite the fact that jquery is obviously referenced.

Comment: @MRFerocius `btn` and `form` are already jQuery Objects so don't wrap them again `$(btn)` use directly `btn`

Comment: This is why I love Stackoverflow, I spent 5 days reading bootbox api, bla bla and then you in 3 min fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @MRFerocius I also love StackOverflow very much .Help learn n grow :)